# How to setup my project to debug the jest test in VS code

Tags: typescript, jestjs, micro-frontend

I am working on a micro frontend project. I installed jest extension for debugging, the questions is when I put the debugger statement into the code, it tests all the code but I cannot debug.

`package.json` scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-env -- react-scripts test",
    "test:coverage": "react-env -- react-scripts test --watchAll=false --coverage --collectCoverageFrom=src/{components,hooks,pages,layout,skeletons,utils}/**/*.{ts,tsx}",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "prestart": "react-env --",
    "eslint": "eslint --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx src",
    "eslint:fix": "eslint --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx src --fix",
    "stylelint": "stylelint **/*.{css,scss}",
    "stylelint:fix": "stylelint --fix **/*.{css,scss}",
    "lint": "npm run eslint && npm run stylelint",
    "lint:fix": "npm run eslint:fix && npm run stylelint:fix",
    "docker:build": "docker build -t front .",
    "docker:start": "docker run -p 9000:3000 --env-file ./.env front"
},
```

`launch.json` set up:

```
{
// put this inside /.vscode dir
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
  {
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Jest: current file",
    //"env": { "NODE_ENV": "test" },
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/jest",
    "args": ["${fileBasenameNoExtension}", "--config", "jest.config.js"],
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "disableOptimisticBPs": true,
    "windows": {
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/jest/bin/jest"
    }
  },
]
}
```

**Error**

> Debugger attached.Error: Can't find a root directory while resolving a config file path.
> Provided path to resolve: jest.config.js